# How do I properly scope a Ruby lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have this lambda:

```
echo_word = lambda do |words|
  puts words
  many_words = /\w\s(.+)/
    2.times do
      sleep 1
      match = many_words.match(words)
      puts match[1] if match
    end
  sleep 1
end
```

I want to pass it to `each` as a block, and many more each blocks in the future.

```
def is_there_an_echo_in_here *args
  args.each &echo_word # throws a name error
end

is_there_an_echo_in_here 'hello out there', 'fun times'
```

But when I run my_funky_lambda.rb with this lambda method, I get a NameError. I'm not sure what's up with the scope of this lambda, but I can't seem to access it from `is_there_an_echo_in_here`.

`echo_word` is properly scoped and used if I make it the constant `ECHO_WORD` and use it like that, but there has to be a more straightforward solution.

In this scenario, what's the best way to access the `echo_word` lamba from inside `is_there_an_echo_in_here`, e.g. wrapping it in a module, accessing global scope, something else?

Comment: Create a minimal test-case, in one code block. Then you should see the issue. It has to do with the scope (or lack of) for `echo_word`. Nothing about lambdas. Might as well be `x = 2; .. def y; do puts x end` to show this issue.

Comment: lol fair point. Looks like I've spent too much time in node land and confused this with: `var a = 1; var b = function() { console.log(a); }; b()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, regular methods aren't closures. It's for this reason you can't call `echo_word` inside `is_there_an_echo_in_here`.

Blocks are closures, however. In Ruby 2+, you could do this:

```
define_method(:is_there_an_echo_in_here) do |*args|
  args.each &echo_word
end
```

Another way would be to pass `echo_word` as an argument:

```
def is_there_an_echo_in_here *args, block
  args.each &block
end

is_there_an_echo_in_here 'hello out there', 'fun times', echo_word
```